# Best way to enable PXE on 300 Dell machines

Tags: dell, pxe-boot

I have about 300 Dell machines (Optiplex, Latitude, Precision) that I need to enable PXE on.  I'm hoping to avoid going to each and every single one.

Is there a way to remotely push the command out to turn PXE on in the BIOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Dell OMCI](http://www.delltechcenter.com/page/OpenManage+Client+Instrumentation+%28OMCI%29).  With it you can script changes to the BIOS.

> Dell™ OpenManage™ Client Instrumentation (OMCI) is available on Dell
>   OptiPlex™, Dell Precision™, and Dell Latitude™ client systems. Using
>   OMCI, system administrators can remotely manage assets, monitor system
>   health, and inventory deployed systems in the enterprise.
>
> OMCI interfaces with leading enterprise management consoles that
>   support industry standards. This approach helps to ensure that Dell
>   systems can be managed by a broad array of existing enterprise
>   management tools. OMCI also interfaces with Dell OpenManage products
>   such as IT Assistant and OpenManage Client Connector. Finally, tight
>   integration with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) allows
>   customers to take advantage of the rich scripting capabilities for
>   collecting information and customizing system settings. OMCI is
>   provided at no additional charge to Dell customers.